# HttpListener doesn't get OPTIONS request

Tags: c#, http, cors

As simple as that. I have a `HttpListener` listening. Let's ignore rest of the code now. Just the listener listening.

I configured 2 test websites: "local-site-a.com" and "local-site-b.com". I configured them by adding following to my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   local-site-a.com
127.0.0.1   local-site-b.com
```

Site B is hosted in IIS, site A is mapped to my `HttpListener`.

Then I have my JS:

```
async start() {

    var response = await fetch("http://local-site-a.com/add/2/2", { "method": "get", "mode" : "cors", "credentials": "include" });
    var result = await response.json();
    console.dir(result);

}
```

CORS? Easy peasy. I read all about it. Catch the preflight (the "OPTIONS" request) respond with headers for headers. All I can read about it on Internet and Stack Overflow is WHAT EXACTLY TO RESPOND, which is not the question here.

I didn't even expected any problems here, but anyway...

The problem is I don't even get the "OPTIONS" request. The first thing that is caught by my `HttpListener` is "GET" request, and it means it just ignored the "OPTIONS" request, am I right?

I get the "Origin" header in the GET request. Shouldn't it be in an OPTIONS request?

Comment: Why did you tag this as C#? What HTTP client are you using? The automated OPTIONS request is a _feature_ of modern browsers and HTTP libraries. Won't always happen automagically.

Comment: Why C#? Because of .NET `System.Net.HttpListener`. What client? All of them. Latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Geez, I always must find the answer myself:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

> Some requests don’t trigger a CORS preflight. Those are called “simple
>   requests” in this article, though the Fetch spec (which defines CORS)
>   doesn’t use that term. A request that doesn’t trigger a CORS
>   preflight—a so-called “simple request”—is one that meets all the
>   following conditions (...)

So...

I added a custom header to my request, and guess what. Here it comes. I read wrong examples leaving out "SIMPLE REQUESTS" matter completely! Now everything works as expected.